# Uninstalled PHP5.6 not working

Tags: php, php7, php-cli

I've **uninstalled php5.6** on my PC then I **upgrade** to **PHP7.2** but when I checked php cli `php -v`, it's show me like this, it's still show me **PHP 5.6** [image: screenshot]

Anyone can help me out ?

Comment: How did you uninstall 5.6? How did you upgrade to 7.2? And which Ubuntu version are you on? Also, please don't post screenshots of terminal output, instead, paste that output into your question and format them as code by clicking the `{}` icon in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think you should do:

1- Remove your php packages and install php7.2. You can proceed as follows:

```
sudo apt-get purge php5.*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli php7.2-fpm
```

2- Optionally, you can also do: (Just after `sudo apt-get purge php5.*`), to be sure you install php7 freshly.

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
```

3- You can then check the version of your php to be sure. It is done just as you did:

```
php -v
```

4- Remember to leave feedback or accept the answer if it has been of help!

Comment: After removing/purging php5 you could run `apt-get autoremove` to make sure that all automatically installed dependencies are removed before installing php7.

Comment: @danzel thanks, I think I'll edit the answer to add that to it.

Comment: it's weird, i was apt-get purge php5.* it's still show me php 5.6 on cli ...any more solution ?

Comment: @RobyFirnandoYusuf why don't you use `sudo` too? Or are you executing this as #root? Then also did you do `sudo apt-get autoremove` ?

Comment: i am already as root here man ...

Comment: i think my terminal like caching something like that .. any idea ?

Comment: @RobyFirnandoYusuf try to reboot your pc and then follow the steps again... About your terminal caching stuff, I don't really have an idea.

Answer (score 1):

It's not required to purge or remove your old PHP version. You can just do this:

- Install the `php7.2-cli` package:

  ```
  sudo apt install php7.2-cli
  ```
- Tell the system which PHP version the command `php` should use:

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
  ```